# Prove that $T$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis

For $b\gt 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, define $T$ on $C[0,b]$ by $Tf(x)=a+\int_0^xf(t)xe^{xt}\,\mathrm dt$. Prove that $T$ is a contraction. From this, show that there is a unique solution for $f \in C[0,\infty)$ to the integral equation $f(x)=a+\int_0^xf(t)xe^{xt}\,\mathrm dt$.

Ok, so I first have to prove that $\lVert Tf(x) \rVert_{\infty}$ is bounded.

I have $\lVert Tf(x) \rVert_{\infty} \le a + \sup_{x \in [0,b]}\int_0^b|f(t)xe^{-xt}|\,\mathrm dt$ and I know that $\lVert f(x) \rVert_{\infty} \le R$ since $f$ is defined on a compact set, but I'm having trouble comming up with the bound for $\lVert Tf(x) \rVert_{\infty} \le a + \sup_{x \in [0,b]}\int_0^b|f(t)xe^{-xt}|\,\mathrm dt$ .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to show that $Tf$ is bounded on $[0,b]$, if you already know it is continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to show that the $\|Tf -Tg\| \leq \lambda \|f-g\|$ for some $\lambda \in (0,1)$.
Let $x \in [0,b]$. Then 
\begin{align}
|(Tf)(x)-(Tg)(x)| & =  \left|\int_0^x(f(t)-g(t))xe^{-xt}\,\mathrm dt \right| \\
& \leq  \int_0^x| f(t)-g(t)| xe^{-xt}\,\mathrm dt \\
& \leq  \int_0^xxe^{-xt}\,\mathrm dt\cdot \|f-g\|\\
&= (1-e^{-x^2}) \|f-g\|.
\end{align}
Hence $\|Tf-Tg\| \leq (1-e^{-b^2}) \|f-g\|$. Since $(1-e^{-b^2}) <1$, we see that $T$ is a contraction.